# How to create controller actions/methods(best practices/common language)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controllers

I am rather new to rails and programming in general. I feel I have picked up the rails MVC and other concepts pretty well but still have a hard time figuring out the syntax of what goes into controller actions. For example when you create a

```
def edit

end
```

How do you know how to format the contents/inside of that method.

Thus far I have seen alot of this:

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
end
```

If I understand this correctly this is creating an instance of the Product Model and putting it into an instance variable that is accessible by the "new" view in products/view

But let's say I want to edit that. My inclination is to do add the following action in the controller:

```
def edit
  @product = Product.edit
end
```

I'm not sure the syntax `Product.edit` is correct though, not sure how to differentiate between edit and update either. How do I know what calls on my Model Object when creating instance variables? Is there somewhere online I can go to learn this? I have found no where thus far with a good list of commands I can play with.

Comment: Create an application with scaffold, that will contains all the restful actions for app.And you can easily learn the CRUD.

Comment: Personally I very much like `InheritedResources`, which greatly reduces the tedious process of implementing boring standard actions over and over again: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def edit
  @product = Product.edit
end
```

should be

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

simple explanation

The edit action (#method) is called when you call e.q `localhost:3000/products/1/edit`

the `1` is the id of your product which is passed to your controller and can be accessed by using params.

when the user hit edit . It is ussually send the data to update action

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.update(params[:product].permit(:title, :desc))
end
```

Ok i know i'm not explain it good enough. You really need to read this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

To edit something, first you need to have (or get, or create, or etc...) it. In the *new* method, you just create new instance of *Product*, this is not necessary, but needs for *form_for* helper, and generally good practice, because it you can use same form for creating and editing. *Product.new* just creates new product and initialize its fields with default values. *Product.find* searches product (single) in database by *id* and returns it. So for editing you first need to find your product, then it will be used to fill fields in editing form, and than in *update* method you will update it:

```
def update
  target_product_required
  @product.assign_attributes(product_params)

  if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
  else
    render :edit
  end
end

def target_product_required
  @product ||= Product.find(params[:id])
end

def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :available_quantity, :image, :remote_image_url)
end
```

This is common pattern: target_product_required returns/assigns founded by id in params product to instance variable, product_params returns product specified params. More about this read in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/